# Counting on dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like

`A B
A E
B E
B C
..`

I want to convert it to two dataframes

One is counting how many times A, B, C.. appear in the first column and other one is counting how many times A, B, B .. appear in the second column.

`A 5
B 4
...`

Could you give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try plyr library:

```
 library(plyr)
 myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(cbind( c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), c("B", "E", "E", "C", "C", "E") ))
 count(myDataFrame[,1])  ##prints counts of first column
 count(myDataFrame[,2])  ##prints counts of second column
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns, get the frequency with `table`, convert to `data.frame` and if needed as separate datasets, use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(df1, function(x)
      as.data.frame(table(x))), paste0("df", 1:2)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You could also use the dplyr library-

```
library("dplyr")
df<- as.data.frame(cbind( c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), c("B", "E", "E", "C", "C", "E") ))
names(df)<-c("V1","V2")
df <- tbl_df(df)
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(c1 = n()) ## for column 1
df %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(c1 = n()) ## for column 2
```